# Format Date type using a function in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a function for date conversion, that accepts a `datetime` argument and returns `string`. How can I use this function to format `Date` columns in a Kendo Grid?

I've tried the following codes, and none of them worked

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).ClientTemplate(@Utility.GetPersianDate((DateTime)"#: ModifyDate #"));

columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).Template(@<text>@Utility.GetPersianDate((DateTime)@item.ModifyDate)</text>);

columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).Format(@Utility.GetPersianDate(Convert.ToDateTime("#: ModifyDate")));
```

I've also tried to convert it on the server side, but it's not possible, since the formatted date is not recognized as a valid date. It's not important, because it's just for display. Users are not supposed to change or enter that date. If nothing works, I might consider using `string` instead of `DateTime` and convert it on the server.

Comment: I think converting it on server is a perfectly valid way to achieve it, cause since it's formatted date it's no more than just a string, a representation of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why your code doesn't work.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).ClientTemplate(@Utility.GetPersianDate((DateTime)"#: ModifyDate #"));
```

This isn't working because the server code runs first, so `"#: ModifyDate #"` can't be converted to a `DateTime`. It should be `InvalidOperationException` or something.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).Template(@<text>@Utility.GetPersianDate((DateTime)@item.ModifyDate)</text>);`
```

The second line doesn't work because of a strange `Template` call. It should be called like this: `.Template(item => Utility.GetPersianDate(item.ModifyDate))`
and it will do the job unless you're using Ajax binding, in which case you cannot use `Template` method.

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ModifyDate).Format(@Utility.GetPersianDate(Convert.ToDateTime("#: ModifyDate")));`
```

The third line doesn't work because `Format` should be called like `Format("{0:D}")`, and it can't accept any other arguments.

So if you're not using Ajax binding, the correct `Template` call should do the trick. If you do, than you can either convert it on the server-side or write a Javascript function to convert date to persian and call it in `ClientTemplate` like this: `.ClientTemplate("# convertToPersian(ModifyDate) #")`

I personally recommend you to do it on server-side like this:

```
public class SomeView
{
  public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

  public string ModifyDatePersian { get { return Utility.GetPersianDate(ModifyDate); } }
}
```

and use it on client-side like this: `.ClientTemplate("#: ModifyDatePersian) #")`.

Comment: Thanks Saito for great explanation, I'm using Ajax Binding and I'll try your second suggestion.

Comment: What's the correct syntax to use the js var inside the razor call? Maybe I should use an Ajax call? `return @Utility.GetPersianDate(@:date);`

Comment: @Akbari I've updated my answer to show how to convert date on server side

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use Kendo it's own parse/format function, in short example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.dummyHistoryList)
                .Name("Grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                   columns.Bound(model => model.dueDate).ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(dueDate),'dd MMM yyyy') #");
                   columns.Bound(model => model.DueItem);
                   columns.Bound(model => model.dueAmount).Format("{0:#,##0.00}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
                })
                .Pageable()
                //and so on....
                )
```

To override a JQuery validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }

            var ok = true;
            //Here I use kendo parse to validate the format
            //you want or you can make your own/implement your
            //validation code below here. (Example)
            if ((kendo.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy")) == null){
                ok = false;
            }
            //END
            return ok;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Read additional format to KendoUI DatePicker. Simply add the parseFormat:

```
.ParseFormats(new List<string> { "yyyy-MM-dd", "MM-dd-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy" })//So On...
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I know how to format Date using kendo functions. But I need to call my own function to convert the date to Persian date, it's not just formatting. The output is like, `94/03/14`, which is not a valid date.

Comment: As for the date validation, I assume you have no problem in server-side script (C#/Razor).
Problem is at Javascript(In specific, Jquery.validation). It expect to have (yyyy-MM-dd) for your input. I have the date validations problem in my current involved project. What I do is, provide an override validation function in Jquery. I will post another answer. A min please. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for JQuery validation, you mean I have to convert them on the server?

Comment: No really, if you want to pass desire format (e.g. 94/03/14) then you have to do something at C#(convert to dateTime) which will be pain in the ass but if your system already have the solution then it's ok. Use the ".ParseFormats()" in MVC KendoUI for the reading/initiate input for server and submit.